# Why aren't Style Sets saved with a document?

Tags: microsoft-word

1. Don't Style Sets differ from Styles? Style Sets comprise different Styles (Headings, subheadings, regular text, …).
2. Pls see the emboldened phrase beneath. Why aren't Style Sets saved with a document?
3. What are Style Sets' advantages over Styles? I don't understand [Allen Wyatt](https://www.fairmormon.org/authors/wyatt-allen)'s [dislike of Style Sets](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T009689_Understanding_Style_Sets.html) - is he correct?

> Word does allow you to create custom Style Sets by modifying existing Style Sets and then saving your modifications under a new name. **Since the Style Set you create is not saved with a document**, that custom Style Set will not be available as an option if you move the document to a different computer. Again, it is only for convenience in specifying what styles should appear in the Styles gallery on a single computer.
>
> If you want to take advantage of styles fully, use the Styles task pane and save your custom styles in a template that can be moved to other computer systems, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft calls them *Quick Styles* and are meant for people who don't want to fuss with formatting individual styles and are merely used as suggested formatting. You still need to apply styles to the different elements in your document, Quick Styles merely applies a format across all styles (so long as they are part of the style set). Style sets are part of the normal.dotm global template stored on your computer so if you switch computers, those styles will not be available. All you need to do is create a template that includes all the style levels and formatting you prefer and save it as a template on the *Design* ribbon. When you move to another computer, just transfer the styles in the template to the normal.dotm on the other computer. To do that, go to *Manage Styles* (one of the icons at the bottom of the styles pop-out window), select *Import/Export* and then move the styles from your document to normal.dotm.

[image]